# Why is a PDB file's age incremented

Tags: tfsbuild, pdb-files

I'm experiencing an issue where I build a project with VS2013, and compare the age between the sole DLL and it's PDB where I find a match, but the same project built on our team foundation server has an age mismatch.

As far as I can tell the project is only being compiled once, so the PDB should not be recompiled, and the workspace within TFS is deleted and recreated each time, so a fresh PDB should be created.

What else can I look at in determining why an age mismatch is occuring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem identified: A standard build definition on Team Foundation Server will by default allow Source Indexing, this is a subsequent edit to the PDB file which increments its age